# @Html.DropDownList rendering different HTML and not returning but default

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

Two identical @Html.DropDownList statement are rendering different HTML. The second works OK, but the first always returns de default value, no matter what was chosen.

The @Html.DropDownList statments are in the following code:

```
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.UnidadeId, "Unidade", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.DropDownList("UnidadeId", (SelectList)ViewBag.UnddId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UnidadeId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UnidadeConsumoId, "Unidade de Consumo", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("UnidadeConsumoId", (SelectList)ViewBag.UndConsId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UnidadeConsumoId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

And the HTML it's rendering:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-md-2" for="UnidadeId">Unidade</label>
<div class="col-md-10">
    <select class="form-control" id="UnidadeId" name="UnidadeId">
        <option value="1">cx</option>
        <option value="2">pc</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="3">kg</option>
        <option value="4">mt</option>
        <option value="5">rl</option>
        <option value="6">ml</option>
        <option value="8">na</option>
        <option value="9">hr</option>
        <option value="10">un</option>
        <option value="11">lt</option>
    </select>
    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="UnidadeId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="UnidadeConsumoId">Unidade de Consumo</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
    <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Unidade de Consumo must be a number." data-val-required="The Unidade de Consumo field is required." id="UnidadeConsumoId" name="UnidadeConsumoId">
        <option value="1">cx</option>
        <option value="2">pc</option>
        <option value="3">kg</option>
        <option value="4">mt</option>
        <option value="5">rl</option>
        <option value="6">ml</option>
        <option value="8">na</option>
        <option value="9">hr</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="10">un</option>
        <option value="11">lt</option>
    </select>
        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="UnidadeConsumoId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

To keep all information together, the list are generated by:

```
ViewBag.UnddId = new SelectList(db.Unidades, "UnidadeId", "Apelido", insumo.UnidadeId);
ViewBag.UndConsId = new SelectList(db.Unidades, "UnidadeId", "Apelido", insumo.UnidadeConsumoId);
```

Where Unidade is:

```
public class Unidade
{
    public int UnidadeId { get; set; }
    public string Apelido { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
}
```

As can been seen the "select" statement are different, so are the results. The first dropdown list returns only the default value where the second returns the chosen one... I can't figure by myself what's goin on... Thank you in advance!

The GET code is:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    Insumo insumo = db.Insumos.Find(id);
    if (insumo == null) return HttpNotFound();
    ViewBag.UnddId = new SelectList(db.Unidades, "UnidadeId", "Apelido", insumo.UnidadeId);
    ViewBag.UndConsId = new SelectList(db.Unidades, "UnidadeId", "Apelido", insumo.UnidadeConsumoId);
    return View(insumo);
}
```

Comment: Can you share your GET action method code ?

Comment: Also the HTML markup you shared is not matching with the razor code!  There is no way it will generate a SELECT element with `name` or `id` **UnId**. Looks like you did not share the proper code in the question!!!

Comment: Also, you should consider using a view model and pass the collection via that while using the `Html.DropDownListFor` helper method which will properly bind the items

Comment: @Shyju I posted the GET code at the end...

Comment: Read my second comment and third comment

Comment: @Shyju, you're right, I pasted the code of a experience I've made... Just corrected... The names are as it appears..

Comment: The fact the the 1st does not have the `data-val-*` attributes suggests you have included another (probably hidden) input for `UnidadeId` before the dropdownlist which would explain why the initial value is posted back (the `DefaultModelBinder` reads the 1st value for a property and ignores other name/value pairs for the same property)

Comment: @StephenMuecke you got it all!!!!! Don't you want to post as solution so that I can give you the acknowledgement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact the the first `<select>` you are rendering with `@Html.DropDownList("UnidadeId", ... )` does not have any `data-val-*` attributes means that you have another input for the `UnidadeId` property generated with a `HtmlHelper` method (I assume a `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UnidadeId)`) before the `@Html.DropDownList()` method.

Internally, the html helpers that generate form controls call the `GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes()` method of `HtmlHelper`. From the [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/HtmlHelper.cs)

> Only render attributes if unobtrusive client-side validation is enabled, and then only if we've never rendered validation for a field with this name in this form. Also, if there's no form context, then we can't render the attributes (we'd have no to attach them to).

When you POST the form, the `DefaultModelBinder` sets the value of your `UnidadeId` based on the first matching name/value pair from the request (your hidden input) and ignores subsequent matching name/value pairs, which explain why you are getting the original value of `UnidadeId`, not the value that is selected in your dropdownlist.

As a side note, setting the 4th parameter in your `new SelectList()` constructor is pointless since its ignored by your `DropDownList()` method (its the value of the property you are binding to that determines what is selected).